# How would I be able to modify classes inside a function?

Tags: python, class

I'm really new to the concept of classes in Python so please excuse my lack of understanding... I'm trying to make a basic and simple fighting RPG based off a YouTube tutorial I saw a while back. I had the idea that your character's health would be based on "90 + level * 10". And this worked great up until I tried to level my character, to find that the level increased but the health stayed the same as when I first loaded the program. I understand why it's doing this but is there a way to almost bypass and get it to update based on the level?

Here's a bit of the code

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.level = 1
        self.maxhealth = 90 + self.level * 10
        self.health = self.maxhealth
PlayerIG = Player()
```

Comment: So you want the value of `self.health` to automatically update when the value of `self.level` changes?

Comment: That is exactly what I'm looking for @leaf

Answer (score 2):

Define `health` as a function, not a property

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.level = 1
        self.maxhealth = 90 + self.level * 10

    def health(self):
        return 90 + self.level * 10
PlayerIG = Player()
print(PlayerIG.health())
```

or provide a function that updates `health`, and call it whenever you level up.

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.level = 1
        self.update_health()

    def update_health(self):
        self.health = 90 + self.level * 10

    def level_up(self):
        self.level += 1
        self.update_health()
```

Comment: @Jonathan Don't use edits to change the spirit of an answer. I was actually going to add another solution similar to this.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I'm using the first answer as a base but when I try to print the results I only get the location of the method. How can I print the value?

Comment: @ShoesBeCodin Are you sure you are printing `PlayerIG.health()` and not `PlayerIG.health`  ? Note the parenthesis as you actually want the method to be called.

Answer (score 0):

`__init__` is only run when you instantiate your class. I'm guessing you are currently updating a player's level doing `PlayerIG.level +=1`. If you do that `__init__` is not ran again and therefore the maxhealth is not updated so you are going to want a level up method.

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, level): # allows you to create a player of level != 1
        self.level = level
        self.maxhealth = 90 + self.level * 10
        self.health = self.maxhealth

    def level_up(self):
        self.level += 1
        self.maxhealth += 10

PlayerIG = Player(1) # creates a player of level 1 and maxhealth 100
PlayerIG.level_up() # PlayerIG is now level 2 with a maxhealth of 110
```